# Using parquet tools on files in hdfs

Tags: maven, hdfs, parquet, parquet-mr

I downloaded and built parquet-1.5.0 of https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr.

I now want to run some commands on my parquet files that are in hdfs. I tried this:

```
cd ~/parquet-mr/parquet-tools/src/main/scripts
./parquet-tools meta hdfs://localhost/my_parquet_file.parquet
```

and I got:

> Error: Could not find or load main class parquet.tools.Main

Comment: Is answer helpful?

Answer (score 3):

Download jar
Download the jar from maven repo, or any location of your choice. Just google it. The time of this post I can get the parquet-tools from here.

If you’re logged in the hadoop box:

wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/parquet/parquet-tools/1.9.0/parquet-tools-1.9.0.jar

This link might stop working few days later. So get the new link from maven repo.

Build jar
If you are unable to download the jar, you could also build the jar from source. Clone the parquet-mr repo and build the jar from the source

git clone https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr

mvn clean package

Note: you need maven on your box to build the source.

Read parquet file
You can use these commands to view the contents of the parquet file-

Check schema for s3/hdfs file:

```
hadoop jar parquet-tools-1.9.0.jar schema s3://path/to/file.snappy.parquet

hadoop jar parquet-tools-1.9.0.jar schema hdfs://path/to/file.snappy.parquet
```

Head file contents:

```
hadoop jar parquet-tools-1.9.0.jar head -n5 s3://path/to/file.snappy.parquet
```

Check contents of local file:

```
java -jar parquet-tools-1.9.0.jar head -n5 /tmp/path/to/file.snappy.parquet

java -jar parquet-tools-1.9.0.jar schema /tmp/path/to/file.snappy.parquet
```

More commands:

```
hadoop jar parquet-tools-1.9.0.jar –help
```

Comment: Do you find this solution useful?

Answer (score 0):

The script is built on the assumption that `parquet-tools-<version>.jar` is located in a directory called `lib` next to the script file itself, like so:

```
$ find -type f
./parquet-tools
./lib/parquet-tools-1.10.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

You can set up such a file layout by issuing the following commands from the root of the parquet-mr git repo (of course many alternative ways and installation locations are possible):

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/parquet-tools/lib
cp parquet-tools/src/main/scripts/parquet-tools ~/.local/share/parquet-tools/
cp parquet-tools/target/parquet-tools-1.5.0.jar ~/.local/share/parquet-tools/lib
```

After this you can run `~/.local/share/parquet-tools/parquet-tools`. (I tested this with version 1.10.1-SNAPSHOT though instead of 1.5.0.)